# How can I aggregate intel amplifier batch results?

Tags: profiling, performance-testing, intel-vtune

I'm solving a number of instances with my code and I'd need to find the worst hotspots, where "worst" is defined as a hotspot over a wide range of instances. So for every instance I have collected hotspot analysis data in batch mode using amplxe-cl. Now I'd like to aggregate this data, I'd like to analyze them together. Is there any way to do this with vtune?

Update:

This is not an mpi application. There are a number of different datasets (problems, instances, pick your term :-) that need to be processed by my application. Depending on the data in a single instance the application can take very different turns while processing it, thus running the application on different instances can result in different hotspots. The purpose of the aggregation would be, as @ArunJose_Intel guessed, is to find hotspots that are common in all runs, that are present in the processing of all kind of instances.

I can collect hotspot analysis for every instance easily using batch mode and I can inspect them individually, but I'd like to see an aggregate analysis.

Of course, I could just process them in one run one after the other, but that would take several weeks, while I can process them as individual problems in a few hours on a cluster of identical machines.

Comment: Are you running an mpi application? Could you provide more clarity on what you imply by instances. Are you referring to multiple executions of your program on the same machine by saying instance?  Or is this some scenario where you are running each run on diff machines ? It would be best if you could explain what actually changes b/w 2 instances

Comment: Also what would be the purpose of aggregation is it just to compare across diff 
"instances" or you are looking to find  what is the common hotspot?

Comment: Edited question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vtune it is not  possible to combine multiple GUI reports. You have an option to [compare](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/analyze-performance/manage-result-files/comparing-results.html) across two different reports to see what has changed but clearly this is not what you are looking for.

A workaround you could possibly try is to create  command line reports from the vtune results you have already collected. These command line reports would be in  easily parsable data formats like  **CSV** . Once you have reports in these formats you could have could write your custom scripts/code to aggregate multiple of these csv reports, with whatever logic you wish to have them aggregated.

Please find below some samples to create command line reports

1)Generate a Hotspots report from the r001hs result on Linux*, and save it to /home/test/MyReport.txt in **text** format.

```
vtune -report hotspots -result-dir r001hs -report-output /home/test/MyReport.txt
```

2)Generate a hotspots report in the **CSV** format from the most recent result and save it in the current Linux working directory. Use the format option with the csv argument and the csv-delimiter option to specify a delimiter, such as comma.

```
vtune -R hotspots -report-output MyReport.csv -format csv -csv-delimiter comma
```

For more information

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/command-line-interface/generating-command-line-reports.html

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/command-line-interface/generating-command-line-reports/saving-and-formatting-reports.htm

Comment: I was afraid of this :-(. I'll do the text output and slicing/dicing the results, but a gui would be so much nicer... Since you seem to be working for Intel, could you log a feature request for this? :-) Thanks!

Comment: @LaszloLadanyi Could you raise this as a feature request by creating a thread in https://community.intel.com/t5/Analyzers/bd-p/analyzers so this could be tracked.